# how to store questions from a database on a servlet and display on an html page? Quiz application

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

I'm a newbie to jsp and servlets! I have to create a quiz application. I've created a list of questions and answers in a MYSQL database. How do I store these questions and display them on HTML pages, validate the answers and display the score?
I don't know HOW to store the questions. Display them ONE by ONE and VALIDATE THEM!
Help!

Answer (score 0):

I will only explain the concepts of creating a simple quiz. Now you did not provide any information like: would the quiz results be saved? Can someone make a new quiz via the application itself? Etc.
I also recommend reading a Spring and/or J2EE book or watch a tutorial of creating a basic CRUD application before you move on.

Anyway, here I explain the **concept** of creating a **simple** quiz! It is not safe (the user can change his answers after submitting for example). But it's only to give you an example of how to set up a (simple!) quiz.

Create a table 'Questions' and a table 'Answers'. If you will have multiple quizzes, you would also have a 'Quiz' table. The question table will then have an extra column called 'quiz_id'.

A row in the question table should contain your question. Columns you may want to use are: (obviously) id, question.

I assume the quiz will be multiple choice. So in the answers table, you would have an 'id', 'question_id', 'answer' and an 'is_correct' column. The latter says whether the answer to that corresponding question is correct or not.

So each answer refers to its question (by the question_id). In this case, you could have multiple (correct) answers for one question.

I will give you a hint to show the questions (and possible answers) on every page:
Since this is a simple quiz:

- Use the URL (get parameter) to show a question. That means: *examplesite.com/quiz/3* will, for example, show the third question of the quiz. You will get that question via that parameter and show it on the page. Via that question id, get all the answers from the database and display them to the user in a list (checkbox/radio buttons).
- Now you could either save the selected answer by the user in a database, which is safe if the user disabled his cookies and closes his browser accidentally. But since I am explaining a *simple* quiz and I did not create a separate User table, why not save the answers selected by the user in a session and cookie?
- Check whether the user is on the last question and create a button to show him the results, on another page. E.g. *examplesite.com/quiz/results*

Now again, this is not safe, because the user can still go back to a question and then modify all the answers till he gets a good result. But again, it's just to show you how a basic construction could look like.

Comment: How do I use the URL to show a question? Does it mean i have to create a new jsp page for every question?

Comment: No. You use one (dynamic) jsp page. On that single page, every question will be shown separately (depending on the id).
Whenever someone goes to e.g. example.com/quiz/3, a certain method like the get method could be called. This 'get method' prepares the page (gets the question via the question id and answers from the database) and redirects it to the same jsp every time. So depending on the id, it will always get a different question but it redirects to the same view. 
Please look into the MVC architecture.

Comment: Is there any way I can validate a checked radio button value in the jsp form itself instead of sending to a servlet?